# Django Multiple User types in Django 1.9

Tags: django, multiple-users

I want to create a web app in which I will have two different types of users Employee and Employers. They'll have mostly non common fields.How to implement separate registration of both.
Currently I have inherited from the User model.

## models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):

cname=models.CharField(max_length=250)

def __str__(self):
    return self.cname


class Workplace(User):
 address=models.TextField(max_length=250)
 logo=models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,null=True,blank=True)
 wcategory=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class Employee(User):
 employee_id=models.CharField(max_length=250)
 eworkplace=models.ForeignKey(Workplace,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

In django, you can make them both able to authenticate, or register, by setting a `OneToOneField` to `User` in your WorkPlace and Employee models. If you have set this user as `AUTH_USER_MODEL` = `<yourapp.User>` in settings, you will be able to register with the models that have set this field.

Comment: But we can't have two models simultaneously at once in AUTH_USER_MODEL

Comment: True. Set this value to `AUTH_USER_MODEL = <yourapp.User>` then in the other models that need to register, add: 
`user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='user_account')`